# How does this AGV rotate without rotating the payload?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, robotics

How does the AGV carrying payloads of huge heights as compared to it's size turn without turning the payload? Even if the body is attached to a center bearing, the bearing is very smooth then how come these bots are able to rotate so precisely?

[image: Alibaba's agv deployed in its warehouse]

Answer (score 1):

A platten or load table driven by hydraulics or an electric motor or large stepper motor will rotate the load to counter the movement of the driving unit.

Answer (score 1):

Some use omni wheels, others use mecanum wheels.
https://www.superdroidrobots.com/shop/category.aspx/robot-kits-omni-wheels/61/

It can also just sit the stack down on it's legs when turning if it needs to.